# List View for Most Recent 5000

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view-threshold

Is it possible to display the most recent 5,000 items in a list using the ID ?  If the answer is yes, then how ?  Also, is the ID inherently have an index ?

I noticed when I tried to create an Index on ID it was not an available field.

Answer (score 1):

if the concern is just to get the most recent items, get it on the basis of Created date.

Comment: How would I get the most recent 4,999 based on Created Date ?

Answer (score 0):

5000 is the list item limit for a view, or as Microsoft puts it, "approximately 5000". ([Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)) So in theory the number is achievable.

ID has an incremental number as its value, but it is not available as a column to be shown. If you want to use it, you may achieve it by creating a calculated column which uses the value of `[ID]`. Bear in mind, that when a list item is removed, its index value becomes empty.

Comment: If I create a calculated column then how do I view the most recent 5,000

Comment: @daPlayaURH The item limit for a view is defines in the list's view settings. Adjust the item limit -setting according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make a view that shows items sorted by Created or Modified date to see the recent items in the list according to that. I wouldn't rely on ID's alone because they increase as time goes by but don't get replaced or re-used when users delete items in the list.

According to this the built in ID column is already indexed as it is a system field(column). 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx

Comment: But if I sort on Created date and it gets beyond 5,000 I will not be able to view the list ?  What am I missing ?  thx

Comment: dealing with larges lists that exceed 5000 doesn't matter what you sort by. its a combination of using column indexing, using filers, and folders is what helps you overcome this. There are several articles on the web that talk about the 5000 view limit. See this slide deck for more: https://www.slideshare.net/gzelfond/sharepoint-5000-item-list-view-threshold-checklist-and-best-practices